# Using variables or constants in nextjs api

Tags: rest, variables, next.js, constants

I'm trying to use a constant in my API. This constant is an array where I can push or pop objects. I populate it through API calls. This is the code:

```
const washes = [];

export default async (req, res) => {
    if(req.method === 'GET')
    {
        res.json({washes});
    }

    if(req.method === 'POST')
    {
        washes.push(req.body);
        console.log(washes);
        res.json({washes});
    }

}
```

I make calls from the front-end to populate the array and to retrieve it. The problem is that, sometimes I get an empty array an sometimes I get the expected array. Or after a while I always get the empty array, like if it was restarted.

I deployed the application on Vercel.

Is there something I'm missing from the back-end functionality, or is it related to Vercel?. Last but not least is it a good practice to use variables or constants in back-end.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cant use an array as storage. You need to connect it to a database of sorts.

When you use this endpoint it will only retrieve the correct array sometimes, because it's stored in a temporary memory on the server.

Look into firebase if you easily want to setup up a project and store information in a database.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup

Another way is to use a .json file in the back-end

Read more here: https://jasonwatmore.com/post/2021/08/28/next-js-read-write-data-to-json-files-as-the-database

**USER EXAMPLE**

```
const fs = require('fs');

// users in JSON file for simplicity, store in a db for 
production applications
let users = require('data/users.json');

export const usersRepo = {
    getAll: () => users,
    getById: id => users.find(x => x.id.toString() ===     id.toString()),
    find: x => users.find(x),
    create,
    update,
    delete: _delete
};

function create(user) {
    // generate new user id
    user.id = users.length ? Math.max(...users.map(x => x.id)) + 1 : 1;

    // set date created and updated
    user.dateCreated = new Date().toISOString();
    user.dateUpdated = new Date().toISOString();

    // add and save user
    users.push(user);
    saveData();
}

function update(id, params) {
    const user = users.find(x => x.id.toString() === id.toString());

    // set date updated
    user.dateUpdated = new Date().toISOString();

    // update and save
    Object.assign(user, params);
    saveData();
}

// prefixed with underscore '_' because 'delete' is a reserved word in javascript
function _delete(id) {
    // filter out deleted user and save
    users = users.filter(x => x.id.toString() !== id.toString());
    saveData();

}

// private helper functions

function saveData() {
    fs.writeFileSync('data/users.json', JSON.stringify(users, null, 4));
}
```

Comment: I solved it using a database. I store a new registry for each request.